# How to fill the screen with image in impress.js?

Tags: javascript, css, image, impress.js

My impress.js slides have images that I would like to fill the screen and center, here's the code:

```
<div id="impress">
    <div class="step" data-x="-10000" data-y="100" data-z="0"  data-scale="1">
        Introduction
    </div>
    <div class="step" data-x="-10000" data-y="-1100" data-z="1000" data-scale="1">
        <img src="images/Wallpaper-Abstract-Fractal-Flowers-Lilies.jpg" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Right now it looks like below, but I'd like the image in the second slide to fill up the screen (maintaining aspect ratio).

[image]

Is there some way to zoom in by changing the data-scale or the camera angle? Or will some css tricks suffice? I started with the default [example template](https://github.com/impress/impress.js/wiki/Examples-and-demos).

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the css (X is the number of the step in question):

```
#step-X html,body{
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#step-X img{
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:-100%; bottom:-100%;
    left:-100%; right:-100%;
    margin:auto;
}
```

and this to the html:

```
<div class="step" data-rel-x="2000" data-rel-y="0">
<img src="path/to/image.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this CSS for image, I will work definitely.

```
/* Set rules to fill background */
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;
/* Set up proportionate scaling */
width: 100%;
height: auto;
/* Set up positioning */
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
margin:auto;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work. It does magnify the image a tiny bit but it also shifts the image off center.

Comment: Can you please send me your page link. Then it will be easy to understand

Comment: Please visit to this link http://www.devdiz.com/designing/full-screen-responsive-background/ may be it will help you

Answer (score 1):

I'm personnaly using the great `object-fit: cover/contain;` properties, and I set the size of the picture to the size of the viewport, and it's enough. Note that it also works with videos if you want.

```
.fitImage {
    width:  100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    background: black;
}


.fitImage img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

```
    <div class="step fitImage" data-x="0" data-y="0" data-scale="2">
        <img src="picture.png" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is pretty late. But it may help some googlers (all of us) later :)

The trick is to combine the attribute data-scale=2 (or a bigger number than 2) on the slide, thus we have `<div class="step" data-scale=2></div>`

Then we fill this slide with an image and increase the height and width attributes of the image. Finally we have something like this :

`<div class="step" data-scale=2>
<img src="src/of/image.jpeg" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: -1; width: 9000px; height: 1000px">
</div>`

We can combine data-scale and dimensions (height,width) of the image until we are satisfied with the quality of the image.

Please refer to this link for more details : [Hinco (impress.js contributor) Blog](http://openlife.cc/blogs/2017/october/impressjs-howto-slides-over-background-image)